# How to update my branch with the latest changes from upstream

Tags: github, merge, branch, pull

This question may sound trivial but I really don't know how to do it right... I am working on an open source project and the source codes are on Github, so I've forked that repo, added a "remote upstream" pointing back to that original repo, and also created a branch in my forked repo and made some changes. It looks something like this:

```
$git remote -v
origin    https://github.com/my_github_account/project_name (fetch)
origin    https://github.com/my_github_account/project_name (push)
upstream  https://github.com/project_name/repo_name (fetch)
upstream  https://github.com/project_name/repo_name (push)

$git branch
  master
* test_branch
```

After making some changes on my "test_branch", there are also some new changes in the upstream, so I want to get the latest changes from upstream, merge them to my test_branch and see if everything works fine. I tried:

```
git pull upstream master
```

which works fine for this purpose, but it also created a "new commit", since the commit messages will also be shown when I create a pull request to the project, if I pull the upstream changes frequently in this way, there will be a lot of

```
Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/project_name/repo_name into test_branch
```

messages showing, which is kind of messy to the others and I don't see others' pull requests contain these kind of messages either... (or maybe there is some way to get rid of these messages?)

I also googled it and tried:

```
git pull --rebase upstream master
```

and then do:

```
git push origin test_branch
```

but then I got some error saying something like:

```
 ! [rejected]        test_branch -> test_branch (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/my_github_account/project_name'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Hmm... I don't have a clear picture of what it means... Maybe I was not doing it the right way... So what is usual the procedure of getting the latest changes from the upstream, integrate/merge them into my branch?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second approach is the correct one (replaying your `test_branch` on top of an updated `master`).

But it will also have the expected side-effect of rewriting the history of your test_branch, with you having to force push it to your fork

```
git push --force origin test_branch
```

Since it is your fork and nobody else is working on `origin/test_branch`, it is ok, and even if you had a PR in progress, that Pull Request would detect the force push and update itself accordingly.